# VB Express2010: Getting index or tag in array of PictureBox

Tags: vb.net

VB Express 2010.  Created a Checkerboard of PictureBox - **Dim Board(64) as PictureBox** 
Next, assigned each square an image - similar to this for each row:

```
For x = 1 to 64
    If (x Mod 2 = 1) then 
        Board(x).Image = My.Resources.wsquare
    Else
        Board(x).Image = My.Resources.bsquare
```

Then placed the squares on FormI and assigned the .tag property = to the index like this:

```
For x = 1 to 64
    Board(x).Location = New Point(y,x1)
    Me.Controls.Add(Board(x))
    Board(x).tag = x
    .....parameters for location y, x1 incremented as necessary....
Next
```

**All this worked fine and produced the checkerboard.**  Now I need to know the index or tag when a square is clicked.  I am unsure of how or where in the code to create the EventHandler and then how to reference the index or tag in subsequent methods. The following is wrong but I'm trying.  *Board.Click is not an event of the array* Would greatly appreciate some code examples or instruction to resolve my dilemma.  Pretty new at this.  Thanks in advance

```
Private Sub Clicked()
    AddHandler Board.Click, New EventHandler(AddressOf Board_Click)
End Sub

Private Sub Board_Click()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're pretty close; the bit you seem to be getting hung up on is that the event handler would need to be bound to each element in your `Board` array and not to the array itself (which is what you're trying to do, it looks like).

Here's some steps to get you started....Firstly, I would modify this loop:

```
For x = 1 to 64
    If (x Mod 2 = 1) then 
       Board(x).Image = My.Resources.wsquare
Else
    Board(x).Image = My.Resources.bsquare
```

To become something like:

```
For x = 1 to 64
    Board(x).Name = "Board_" + x.ToString()
    If (x Mod 2 = 1) then 
       Board(x).Image = My.Resources.wsquare
Else
    Board(x).Image = My.Resources.bsquare
```

So we use the [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name.aspx) property of the PictureBox to identify each individual PictureBox. We need this so you know which item got clicked.

Now let's have a dummy handler for the click, like:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim clickedBox As PictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)

    MessageBox.Show(clickedBox.Name)
End Sub
```

Here we are just getting the clicked PictureBox from the [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx) event, casting it to a PictureBox and then emitting its Name property (remember we set that before).

So now we have that, we can revisit your For loop again and bind the handler to the click event of each element in the array, for example:

```
For x = 1 to 64
    Board(x).Name = "Board_" + x.ToString()
    AddHandler Board(x).Click, New EventHandler(AddressOf Me.PictureBox1_Click)
    If (x Mod 2 = 1) then 
       Board(x).Image = My.Resources.wsquare
Else
    Board(x).Image = My.Resources.bsquare
```

Now if you run that you should see when you click on a PictureBox you get a message box displaying "Board_23" or "Board_1" or something like that.

Now to figure out the index in the `Board` array of the element which was clicked you can use something like, for example, [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) or [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) combined with a [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx) to get the numeric part of the name. Because of how we named it previously the numeric component of the name is the array index.

**PS.** It's been a while since I did actual VB.NET but I think that arrays are zero-based and not one-based. I'm not sure, but you might want to check that in your code (as I said, I haven't done real VB.NET for some time)

Comment: Perfect solution provided.  Please accept my thanks.  Your advice and the presentation was outstanding and very easy to understand and implement. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help - if you found the answer useful, please consider marking your question as answered to help others who might have similar problems :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    For x = 0 To 16
        Board(x) = New PictureBox
        Board(x).Name = "Board_" + x.ToString()
        AddHandler Board(x).Click, New EventHandler(AddressOf Me.PictureBox1_Click)
        If (x Mod 2 = 1) Then
            Board(x).Image = My.Resources.green_bullet
        Else
            Board(x).Image = My.Resources.yellow_bullet
        End If
        Board(x).Location = New Point(Board(x).Width * x, 10)
        Me.Controls.Add(Board(x))
        Board(x).Tag = x
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, can you besides posting the code which solves the problem also provide a few lines of explanation (why/how/what/...)?