# Linking correct array of objects with another array of objects in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, combobox

So I have a form with a button "btnAddProduct" and I have two arrays of combo boxes that list products and sub products. When a product is chosen from the first combobox, the second combo box appears so that you can choose from a sublist of products. On load of the form, the first combobox is displayed and if you want to add another product you click a button. The code is:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim gbProduct(5) As GroupBox
Dim lblProduct(5) As Label
Dim cmboBoxProduct(5) As ComboBox
Dim lblSubProduct(5) As Label
Dim cmboBoxSubProduct(5) As ComboBox
Dim pnlProducts As New Panel
Dim n As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    With pnlProducts
        .Width = 500
        .Height = 300
        .AutoScroll = True
    End With
    Me.Controls.Add(pnlProducts)
    n = 0
    addProduct()

    Me.AutoScroll = True

End Sub

Private Sub addProduct()
    ' ----------------Add the groupbox
    gbProduct(n) = New GroupBox
    With gbProduct(n)
        .Text = ""
        .Location = New Point(10, 5 + n * 70)
        .Width = 400
        .Height = 70
    End With
    pnlProducts.Controls.Add(gbProduct(n))

    '------------------ Add the product dropdown
    lblProduct(n) = New Label
    With lblProduct(n)
        .Text = "Product"
        .Location = New Point(10, 15)
        .Width = 50
    End With
    gbProduct(n).Controls.Add(lblProduct(n))

    cmboBoxProduct(n) = New ComboBox
    With cmboBoxProduct(n)
        .Items.Add("A")
        .Items.Add("B")
        .Items.Add("C")
        .Text = ""
        .Location = New Point(60, 15)
    End With
    gbProduct(n).Controls.Add(cmboBoxProduct(n))
    AddHandler cmboBoxProduct(n).SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf subProducts
End Sub

Private Sub subProducts()

    Try
        gbProduct(n).Controls.Remove(cmboBoxSubProduct(n))
    Catch

    End Try

    '------------------ Add the product dropdown
    lblSubProduct(n) = New Label
    With lblSubProduct(n)
        .Text = "Product"
        .Location = New Point(190, 15)
        .Width = 50
    End With
    gbProduct(n).Controls.Add(lblSubProduct(n))

    cmboBoxSubProduct(n) = New ComboBox
    Select Case cmboBoxProduct(n).Text
        Case "A"
            With cmboBoxSubProduct(n)
                .Items.Clear()
                .Items.Add("AA")
                .Items.Add("AB")
                .Items.Add("AC")
                .Text = ""
                .Location = New Point(240, 15)
            End With
        Case "B"
            With cmboBoxSubProduct(n)
                .Items.Clear()
                .Items.Add("BA")
                .Items.Add("BB")
                .Items.Add("BC")
                .Text = ""
                .Location = New Point(240, 15)
            End With
        Case "GenieMat FF"
            With cmboBoxSubProduct(n)
                .Items.Clear()
                .Items.Add("CA")
                .Items.Add("CB")
                .Items.Add("CC")
                .Text = ""
                .Location = New Point(240, 15)
            End With

    End Select

    gbProduct(n).Controls.Add(cmboBoxSubProduct(n))
End Sub

Private Sub btnAddProduct_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddProduct.Click
    n += 1 'increment array index when button clicked
    addProduct()
    Me.Refresh()

End Sub

End Class
```

This works fine as long as you add the subproduct before you click the button. If you click the button first then you increment "n" and then the subproducts don't line up with the correct product. What is the best way to tell the subproduct array which product to associate with?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out and thought I would share. This relates to this question:

[VB Express2010: Getting index or tag in array of PictureBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595328/vb-express2010-getting-index-or-tag-in-array-of-picturebox)

I needed to add this click event:

```
Private Sub cmboBoxProduct_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim clickedComboBoxProduct As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)

    m = clickedComboBoxProduct.Tag
    txtShow.Text = m

End Sub
```

And referenced it by this event handler:

```
AddHandler cmboBoxProduct(n).Click, New EventHandler(AddressOf Me.cmboBoxProduct_Click)
```

Hope this helps anyone else out

Answer (score 0):

I don't know vb, but I know you're stuck. I think the easiest way to do it is add a public check to see if the field is initialized such as:

```
Dim hasText As boolean = false
```

up where you declare n.

Then in your button click event, you'd have a check if hasText==true and only increment n in that scenario. You would set hasText to true with each of the case statements I believe.

In C++, I'd add a member function to the buttonClick Object as sender to check itself for text and only increment n when that's true. I'm not sure if you can do that in vb though!

Answer (score 0):

First, I wouldn't manually maintain the value n, it's not an expensive call in the first place and generally irrelevant to performance on a form.

You only have one try/catch block to perhaps continue execution after an error, but in good practice it would be better to check the count of the controls object which you're attempting to maintain for more robust code.

Second, to fix your issue simply add an if block to your button click event,   pseudocode:

```
If cmboBoxSubProduct has SelectedValue then ' check against text value, etc'
    addProduct()
    Me.Refresh()
Else
    ' show label above add product button explaining they need to select a subproduct'
End If
```

Comment: I don't think that will work but maybe I'm wrong. The way I see it is I need some way to get which product has been selected. I have an array of comboboxes, product(). If there are two showing on screen, how to I get which one was clicked? I need to get the index in the array of which combo box was clicked but I don't know how to do that